# Image automatically given a border?

Tags: html, css, image, border

I have an image that has a transparent background. When I first inserted the image onto the page, it looked completely fine except for the fact that it was way too large. I gave it a height of 50%, and it was outlined in a brighter color. The image itself wasn't outlined, just the area that isn't transparent.

In the image, the background of the website is supposed to be gray. The green is outlined in a brighter green.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSyPY.png

Here's the HTML:
img src="http://i.imgur.com/kA9UjKe.png" style="float:right; height:50%;"

Comment: Can you post a image of what is wrong?

Comment: That is the image itself. can you post an image of what is wrong? It would also be helpful if you posted your CSS for your page.

Comment: Do you want the background of the image to be grey?

Comment: Yes, the background is gray. If you look at the image, the border of the green is lighter. The original image doesn't look like that. When I add a size attribute, such as width or height, it adds the lighter edge. There is no CSS.

Comment: @GarrettSadFace I suspect it has to do with how the colors are compressed when you resize the image. Don't think you can do anything with css or html. I would recommend resizing the image *before* uploading to server. That way you know what you will get + you save bandwidith (if image is resized down in the code, ofc).

Comment: Maybe using a single color will do and will considerably reduce the wheight of your image : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gyEeI http://i.stack.imgur.com/X96gu.png

Comment: IE11 - I put it in a div, took it out, changed the size down to 100px wide and changed it to display: inline - can't see what you describe. http://jsfiddle.net/Bqd82/

Answer (score 0):

Try giving an exact size in the css, no percentage based size. Also add the following css

```
img, img a {border:none}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a univeral CSS reset by  using this code:

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
}
```

But the best thing is to use **[this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)** CSS reset in my opinion